# Calculating score based on rank position

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `jackpot` with columns `uid` for user ID and `nright` for number of right answers.

I manage to SELECT and rank users by right answers, but what next?

```
SELECT
    a1.uid,
    a1.nright,
    COUNT(a2.nright) AS rank
FROM
    jackpot a1,
    jackpot a2
WHERE
    a1.nright < a2.nright
OR (
    a1.nright = a2.nright
    AND a1.uid = a2.uid
)
GROUP BY
    a1.uid,
    a1.nright
ORDER BY
    a1.nright DESC,
    a1.uid DESC
```

I need to calculate the amount of points to give to each user depending on his position.

Only users with top 3 MAX `nright` receive points.

The total amount of points = the number of users*20.

First position gets 70% of the total, 2nd - 20%, 3rd - 10%.

In case of equal right answers between users, the points are split evenly (50/50, 33/33/33...).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50d5f/1)

Comment: It would be really really helpful if you post the DML and DDL of your SQL and also if you make an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decompose what you want.

**1st step** : You want the top 3 scores.

```
SELECT nright 
FROM jackpot
ORDER BY nright DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**2nd step :** The user id who gets this 3 first scores

```
SELECT j.uid
FROM jackpot j
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT nright 
   FROM jackpot
   ORDER BY nright DESC
   LIMIT 3 ) AS t ON t.nright = j.nright
```

**3rd step**: the total amount of point

```
SELECT COUNT(uid)*20 AS lot FROM jackpot
```

**4th step**: the rank and the number of person

Here we need to use a variable, as you are in php, you can't use `set @var:= X;` , so the trick is to do a `Select @var:= X` , this variable will not work because of the aggregate functions. So you need to do this :

```
SELECT  @rank := @rank+1 as rank,T1.nright,T1.nb,T1.lot
FROM(
    SELECT nright,
          COUNT(uid) as nb,
         (SELECT COUNT(uid)*20 FROM jackpot) as lot
   FROM jackpot
   GROUP BY nright
   ORDER BY nright DESC
   LIMIT 3
   )T1, (SELECT @rank:= 0) r
```

**5th step**: The lots distribution

```
 SELECT j.uid,
  CASE 
  WHEN t.rank = 1 THEN (t.lot*0.7)/t.nb
  WHEN t.rank = 2 THEN (t.lot*0.2)/t.nb
  WHEN t.rank = 3 THEN (t.lot*0.1)/t.nb
  END as lot

 FROM jackpot j
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT  @rank := @rank+1 as rank,T1.nright,T1.nb,T1.lot
FROM(
    SELECT nright,
          COUNT(uid) as nb,
         (SELECT COUNT(uid)*20 FROM jackpot) as lot
   FROM jackpot
   GROUP BY nright
   ORDER BY nright DESC
   LIMIT 3
   )T1, (SELECT @rank:= 0) r) t ON t.nright = j.nright
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I get the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rank:=0) r GROUP BY nright, rank ORDER BY nright DESC LIMIT 3 ) AS ' at line 10

Comment: Hm, shouldn't j.uid and j.nright be jackpot.uid and jackpot.nright? Because otherwise it says 'there is no such column in table'. 
I tried changing it but got error: 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Comment: Yes sorry. This is why I shouldn't post any anwser from my work station. :D

Comment: Ok so now I get the other error: 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Comment: So sorry for all this mistakes, i have tested it, it should work.